# how to add stylesheet to particular plugin only?

Tags: plugin-development, admin-css

I am developing plugin wherein I want to add `bootstrap.css` to plugin setting page. But if I add css, it will get add to whole WordPress admin panel.

Is there any way to apply css to particular plugin only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to check which page is being displayed now, and if it was your plugin's page, enqueue the script.

However the easier way is to use the global variable, `$pagenow`:

```
if(( $pagenow == 'my-plugin.php' ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', 'URL-HERE' );    
}
```

In which `my-plugin.php` is the slug of your plugin screen's URL, such as:

```
www.example.com/wp-admin/my-plugin.php
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks ! it works for me. But just queries, as it is on page level, we don't have something on plugin level ? because if I want to do it for multiple pages, then I need to add "&&" in if statement like if(( $pagenow == 'my-plugin.php' &&   $pagenow == 'my-settings.php' ) something like this.

Comment: Yes you can do that too, it's the correct way. You can also use `get_the_current_screen();`, it's a much more powerful function, that also allow queries such as `plugin.php?query=sample`.

Comment: @JackJohansson the function name is `get_current_screen` (not get_the_current_screen)